# js converting string with [*] into variable

Tags: arrays, angular, object, vue.js, object-literal

I've got basic variable that I'm getting from my api:

```
nurseListSpeciality.avatar = "srcs[14]"
```

I want to change srcs[14] into array name, that my object should be like:

```
nurseListSpeciality:[{avatar: srcs[14]}]
```

The main problem is that I don't want to execute the reference on the array, but I want to put just a name of it inside my object.

This is why I failed to use `eval()`. Eval is trying to get `srcs[14]` value and put it into my object. This is not what I want.

Comment: it should be `eval(this.nurseListSpeciality[i].avatar)`

Comment: this gives me `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: srcs is not defined at eval `

Comment: that is probably because you don't have a variable `srcs` in the scope in which `eval` is executed.

Comment: do you have always `srcs` as variable?

Comment: @NinaScholz no, I'm executing method, so in method I need to have `this.srcs` or declare it as a variable inside method. But `it is not the case` I just want to convert `"srcs[14]"`  into `srcs[14]`, not getting `srcs[14] value` inside the object

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to use lodash, using [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get) is a good way to do this:

```
nurseListSpeciality.avatar = _.get(window, "srcs[14]");
```

This code assumes that `srcs` is a variable which is available globally (in `window` object). If you have some other scope, you should replace `window` with the appropriate object.

Comment: I will avoid using lodash at this moment, so I cannot tell if this will work for me

Answer (score 0):

> vuejs console gives:
>
> **`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:  this.nurseListSpeciality[i].eval is
>   not a function`**

Error message tells you that `this.nurseListSpeciality[i]` doesn't have an `eval` method, you need to invoke global `eval` on `this.nurseListSpeciality[i].avatar` as.

```
 eval(this.nurseListSpeciality[i].avatar)
```

**Note**

- This will not work if you don't have a variable `srcs` available in your current scope.

Comment: this will not work because eval will take srcs value from the scope and execute it instead of creating srcs[14] variable from string as it is

Comment: `eval` doesn't create variables unless there is a code to create variables  like  `eval( "var src=[]; src[14]" )`.  If you can state your actual requirement, I can suggest a possible solution.

Comment: hm, let me try this

Comment: Even in this case it `src[14]` will return `undefined` since array size is 0.  Looks like you have a control over what you can pass as value. If you can share the actual requirement, I can suggest a better solution.

Comment: when i declare `let srcs = "random text"` into my method, I've got `undefined`

Comment: because `srcs[14]` will still be `undefined`, make the string of length more than 14 characters.

Comment: but I don't want to get `srcs[*]` value inside my object, I want to get variable name: `srcs[*]`  - this is the case